# Conflict in use WPFToolKit wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a project with VS 2015 in windows 8 . In my project i have a custom `MessageBox` that when i run it, i get an error:

> Exception thrown: 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' in PresentationFramework.dll
>   Additional information: 'Set property 'System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.DeferrableContent' threw an exception.'

In this code in MessageBoxStyle File:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:primatives="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;assembly=PresentationFramework">
```

When i add reference => WpfToolKit to solve this problem but other problems arise:I get an error from this:
`new UserGroupOperationView(AppData.OperationWindowMode.New, null, "Add User Group").ShowDialog();`
  error:

> 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' in PresentationFramework.dll
>   Additional information: 'Provide value on 'System.Windows.Baml2006.TypeConverterMarkupExtension' threw an exception.

I do not know what to do :((((

Comment: *"I do not know what to do"* - First step: please provide a [minimal, complete, verifyable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)